# write an uncompressed bitmap on android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bmp

in my java code I have an mBitmap object.

How can I save this uncompressed bitmap (black&white) to a file like this:
first byte contains the first 8 pixels,
second byte the next 8 pixels... and so on  ?

thanks!